# date and time from sqlite3 db

Tags: database, sqlite, date, time

I am trying to retrieve data which was added on the current day from sqite3 database, if i try to use strftime('%d', saledate) to retrieve/query data of the current day from the saledate column it does not work as expect

```py
self.conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
self.c = self.conn.cursor()
self.c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sales(name TEXT, KSH INTEGER, saledate TIMESTAMP)")

d_s = self.c.execute("SELECT SUM(KSH) FROM sales GROUP BY strftime('%d', saledate), strftime('%d', saledate)").fetchone()
d_s = float(''.join(map(str, d_s)))
self.ui.label_28.setText(str(d_s))
self.ui.label_28.setFont(QFont("Times", 20))
self.ui.label_28.setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);color : white; }")
self.connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `strftime()` is used to format dates or timestamps and when you use the modifier `%d` the result is the day of the date in the format `dd`.
So why do you `group by strftime('%d', saledate)` (and twice)?

If you want the sum of the column `KSH` per day then you should group by day which you can do with the function `date()`:

```
SELECT SUM(KSH) AS total FROM sales GROUP BY date(saledate)
```

If, as you say in your question, you want the sum of the current day, then you don't need to `group by`:

```
SELECT SUM(KSH) AS total FROM sales WHERE date(saledate) = current_date
```

Note that this will work only if your timestamps in the table are in the format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` which is the only valid date format in SQLite.

Comment: what if i wanted it to be the current month

Comment: @Ericpaul change the WHERE clause to: `WHERE strftime('%Y%m', saledate) = strftime('%Y%m', current_date)`